# Finding complete sequences using a RavenDb index

Tags: mapreduce, ravendb

I have documents in RavenDb that may look something like this:

```
{ "Id": "obj/1", "Version": 1 },
{ "Id": "obj/1", "Version": 2 },
{ "Id": "obj/1", "Version": 3 },
{ "Id": "obj/1", "Version": 4 },
{ "Id": "obj/2", "Version": 1 },
{ "Id": "obj/2", "Version": 2 },
{ "Id": "obj/2", "Version": 3 },
{ "Id": "obj/3", "Version": 1 },
{ "Id": "obj/3", "Version": 3 }
```

I'm trying to create an index that would give me:

- The sequences "obj/1" and "obj/2", preferably grouped by Id.
- Not the sequence "obj/3", since its not yet complete

How would I do this?

Comment: How do you define a complete sequence? Have sequential ids?

Comment: 1, 2, 3 is complete whereas 1, 3 has a hole and is not complete. The Version is a sequential counter. This will be used in an event processor. I will execute event sequences as they become complete. I'm spiking a simple read model thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it. I'm not sure it is the optimal solution but it seems to work.

```
class SequenceIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<MyObject>
{
    public EventSequenceIndex()
    {
        Map = objects => from d in docs
                         orderby d.Version
                         select new
                         {
                             Id = d.Id,
                             Version = d.Version
                         };

        TransformResults = (database, results) => 
            from result in results
            group result by result.Id into g
            where g.Select(d => d.Version + 1)
               .Except(g.Select(d => d.Version))
               .Count() == 1
            select new
            {
                Id = g.Key,
                Objects = g
            };
    }
}
```

With query:

```
var events = session.Query<MyObject, SequenceIndex>()
    .As<MySequenceObjectView>()
    .ToArray();
```

I group the documents by Id and then take all `version + 1` except all `version`, which for an original sequence of `1, 2, 3` will be `2, 3, 4 except 1, 2, 3`, which gives me `4` (which is why I use the `Count() == 1`. But if there is a hole in the sequence, the count would be greater than 1, and therefore excluded from the results.