# How to query RavenDb index and perform changes on the result

Tags: ravendb

I'm experimenting a bit with RavenDb.

I have grouping indexes (Map/Reduce and Live Projection).

I want to take the result from those indexes and update the documents from which the result is projected from.

This is part of an execution pipeline where Raven serves as a queue. The grouping is crucial. And when one of the grouped documents has been processed I want to mark it as processed.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use the indexed properties bundle:

https://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/browse_thread/thread/d51f2f625635a624/dd6ef0498cc24175

Comment: I'm not sure sure how I would use that. I'm getting the docs to execute using something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173627/finding-complete-sequences-using-a-ravendb-index and what I want to do is simply to set a property on the resulting objects and save.
Indexed properties looks like standard Map/Reduce. I might have to give it a go.